# Apache non www to www badly re writting arrays on URL

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

we have the following `.htaccess` configuration:

```
RewriteEngine on
allow from all

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1\.domain2\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain1\.domain2\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.domain1\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.domain1\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

Between other things we want to redirect all non-www URLs to the ones with the www.

Everything works fine, except for the pages where the URL is like this:

```
index?Form%5bplace%5d=Caribbean&Form%5bdestination%5d=Virgin+Islands&Form%5btype%5d=A
```

When we enter the URL without the www our redirect ends up with the following URL:

```
index?Form%255bplace%255d=Caribbean&Form%255bdestination%255d=Virgin+Islands&Form%255btype%255d=A
```

Which gives an 404 error because it is not recognized.

Any idea how to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this:

```
allow from all
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# if a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1\.domain2\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain1\.domain2\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain1.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.domain1.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi, it is still being converted to %255d

Comment: Try using that in a different browser.

Comment: Hi, in chrome and safari doesn't work. But in firefox it works fine. This was happening before I implemented your suggested code. How come it works different in each browser?

Comment: Clear cache from each browser.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that the `%` symbol is getting escaped to `%25`.

[You can avoid this using the `NE` flag on your rules](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne)

Comment: Hi, it is still being converted to %255d

Comment: Hi, the URL is http://ritzycharters.com/yacht/index?SearchForm%5Barea%5D=Caribbean&SearchForm%5Blocation%5D=Virgin+Islands I've added this RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.domain1\.com\/" [R=301,L, NE]